# forming complex number array in python from test file of two column

Tags: python, arrays

I have a two columns in a text file which are separated by spaces as shown below. 
On each line, the first number is the real part of a complex number, and the second one is the imaginary part.

How can I read this file and build a list of complex numbers?

I am reading the text file using `array_name = pd.read_csv(<text_file>,sep='\s+')`.
This needs columns to be named as 'i' and 'q' otherwise it would consider first line as column name.  Even after adding 'i' and 'q' names to the column,  I am unable to form a complex numbers list out of it. I tried multiple options like the one below.  Everything in vain.

```
result = complex(matrix_array['i'],matrix_array['q'])
```

There must be a simple way to do it.

Sample file:

```
262       262  
-219    384  
-312    51  
101     -73  
326     194  
57      188  
-115    -352  
230     -635  
590     -56  
402     680  
7       545  
34      -222
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'complex' number array?

Comment: array[0]=a+jb; array[1]=c+jd; array[2]=e+jf etc....

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate on the lines of the file, `split` each line (by default, `split` will split on any number and kind of whitespace), convert each part to a float, and build the complex number from the real and imaginary part.

So, you could do:

```
out = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        x, y = map(float, line.split())
        out.append(x + y*1j)
print(out)
# [(262+262j), (-219+384j), (-312+51j), (101-73j), (326+194j), (57+188j), (-115-352j), (230-635j), (590-56j), (402+680j), (7+545j), (34-222j)]
```

To answer your comment, I tried and timed some alternatives:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def make_complex_pandas(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    return np.array(df[0]+1j*df[1])


def make_complex_python(filename):
    out = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            x, y = map(float, line.split())
            out.append(x + y*1j)
    return out

def make_complex_numpy(filename):
    arr = np.loadtxt(filename)
    return #arr[:,0] + arr[:,1] * 1j


print('numpy version')
%timeit make_complex_numpy('big_complex.txt')
print('pandas version')
%timeit make_complex_pandas('big_complex.txt')
print('basic_version')
%timeit make_complex_python('big_complex.txt')
```

Here are the results. Note that I'm no expert in pandas and numpy, so there might be better ways to do it.

A large part of the time needed is for parsing the file, that's the main bottleneck when using numpy, as `np.loadtxt` is relatively slow.

The fastest solution depends on the size of the data, as expected: the pure Python solution is much faster with small data, then the pandas one gets faster. Here are timings for files between 10 and 10,000,000 lines:

```
10 lines: basic, numpy, pandas (fastest to slowest) 

numpy version
1000 loops, best of 5: 240 µs per loop
pandas version
100 loops, best of 5: 2.99 ms per loop
basic_version
10000 loops, best of 5: 37.8 µs per loop

100 lines: basic, numpy, pandas 

numpy version
1000 loops, best of 5: 939 µs per loop
pandas version
100 loops, best of 5: 3.04 ms per loop
basic_version
10000 loops, best of 5: 144 µs per loop


1,000 lines: basic, pandas, numpy

numpy version
100 loops, best of 5: 8.21 ms per loop
pandas version
100 loops, best of 5: 3.38 ms per loop
basic_version
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.17 ms per loop

10,000 lines: pandas, basic, numpy

numpy version
10 loops, best of 5: 79.8 ms per loop
pandas version
100 loops, best of 5: 6.37 ms per loop
basic_version
100 loops, best of 5: 11.2 ms per loop

1,000,000 lines:  pandas, basic, numpy

numpy version
1 loop, best of 5: 7.59 s per loop
pandas version
1 loop, best of 5: 298 ms per loop
basic_version
1 loop, best of 5: 1.13 s per loop

10,000,000 lines: pandas, basic, numpy

numpy version
1 loop, best of 5: 1min 19s per loop
pandas version
1 loop, best of 5: 3.23 s per loop
basic_version
1 loop, best of 5: 11.8 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks you. Appreciate the effort.  Is there any other way other than looping over individual lines? I might have a huge set of data.